# How do I solve this double integral for a circular aperture with a y offset?

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve the integral

$$\int\int\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-y_0)^2+R^2}}$$
but not getting very far. It should have limits and in polar coordinates it is up to some fixed angle theta. R is a real constant and $y_0$ is an offset on the $y$ axis. If it's helpful it's the integral of a Lambertian source at some distance R, offset in y.

Comment: What the limits are is rather important to this integral. Do you know what they are? If not, is there something like a diagram they can be inferred from?

Comment: It's just a circular aperture with any radius r, integrated to some fixed angle theta - it's a general case

Comment: At least, write the $\color{red}{\tt limits}$.

Comment: @user192356 That's really not enough info. I'm guessing this aperture is centered at $(0,0)$, but you haven't specified that. And if we're integrating up to a fixed angle $\theta$, what about the lower limit? Is it $0$? Is that the positive $x$-axis, positive $y$-axis, or some other ray?

Answer (score 3):

HINTS:

$$\int\int\frac{dx dy= dx\; d(y-y_0)}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-y_0)^2+R^2}}$$
Convert to polar coordinates

$$\int\int\frac{r dr d \theta}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-y_0)^2+R^2}}$$

$$ \frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}{2} \int\frac{d r^2}{\sqrt{r^2+R^2}}$$

where due to offset reduced limit

$$\theta_1= \pi- \sin^{-1}\frac{y_0}{R};\;\theta_2= -\theta_1 $$

Integral is in the form: $ \;2 \sqrt{r^2+R^2} +c $

Comment: Your third line is unjustified, as depending on the integration region the $r$ limits might depend on $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'm a bit confused how the dr becomes dr^2?

Comment: Please note the differential: $ 2 r\; dr $ became $d(r^2)$